# Replace Windows 7 Entirely W/ Ubuntu & Security Feature Allows Wildows Files?

Tags: system-installation, security

1. If Ubuntu supports files from windows, doesn't this defeat the "security" of Ubuntu? Obviously not a technie
2. How to install and "replace" Windows 7 entirely, and get Microsoft out of my desktop.

Appreciate your help very much.

Comment: How does it defeat this "security"?

Comment: Ubuntu supports *files* (normal things, like pictures or documents) and not *executables* (the viruses, `.exe` format)

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: @muru I'm missing something? How is this a dupe?

Comment: @Braiam for point 2. The usual installation method has an option to "replace" Windows.

Comment: @muru yeah, but I would have selected "too broad" instead. In fact, I would ignore totally this crap and try to delete it.

Comment: @Braiam I'm too lazy. Problem with too broad is that OP doesn't get any automatic feedback until the question is closed. At least with dupes, they get a comment immediately. Then they can chose to remove that question from the post.

Answer (score 1):

Files are just a way to represent data on the computer side, the file system of Windows is supported by Ubuntu and that is obvious, if you can open a jpg photo on windows then you can open it on Ubuntu.

But, if you mean that a virus on Windows does it effect the system on Ubuntu, and the answer is no because executable files on windows are considered as binary files on Ubuntu, and most of the time they don't have  execution  privilege for it to run.

You can install Ubuntu and choose the partition of your hard disk where windows lives to remove Windows.

But you can use both Windows/Ubuntu on the  same machine until you feel yourself comfortable enough with Ubuntu.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

1. .exe files are built specifically for Windows platforms. They are
       compiled using Windows libraries and executed natively only in
       Windows. Same applies to viruses since they are compiled
       specifically for Windows. Hence, Ubuntu, due to its completely
       different set of libraries and structure, is shielded from threats
       arising from .exe files.
2. Get Microsoft out

   - If you want to preserve your files, install Ubuntu on a separate partition (format it as EXT4) and you can easily use Ubuntu without harming any of your existing personal files on Windows.
   - If you want to wipe all Windows files as well as personal data, just format the whole partition to EXT4 and install Ubuntu over it